# Extracting numbers from messy strings, in particular from the Wii Motionplus Controller

Tags: python, string-formatting, wiimote

Below is the output from a wii motionplus controller with buttons and motionplus set as report modes. I've tried interrogating it like I would with the board or accelerometer ie. but it always seems to throw up errors so I decided to treat it as a string instead.

```
{'led': 1, 'rpt_mode': 130, 'ext_type': 4, 'motionplus': {'angle_rate': (8195, 8284, 8167)}, 'buttons': 0, 'rumble': 0, 'error': 0, 'battery': 74}
```

All numbers are constantly changing with time.

Below is the code attempting to tidy it up with:

```
import cwiid, time, re
#Some stuff here for connecting wiimotem create object, etc.

    #Grab state as string,split by whitespace and put into list:
    splitit = str(wm.state).split()
    #Output list
    wmp_out = []
    #Scan across splitit list
    for x in splitit:
        #Remove all non numeric characters from element in list
        s_dat = re.compile(r'[^\d.]+').sub('',x)
        #append to output only if element contains something (i.e. number)
        if len(s_dat) != 0: wmp_out.append(s_dat)
        else: pass
        #Output to screen
        print testarr[3], " ", testarr[4], " ", testarr[5]
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Does anyone else have a better way of doing this? I need the three motionplus values stored in a list. I've seen the values of these hit 0 with extreme rotations so a threshold or won't cut it. In particular I'm really sketchy on the whole re.compile() function... at the moment it'll strip everything except for a decimal place.

Comment: That input value as you've specified it isn't a `str`, it's a `dict`. As written you should simply be able to do `gyro = wii_data['motion_plus']['angle_rate']`

Comment: First thing I tried and it gave an error.

Comment: Frustratingly that form works for all other data I read off it.

Comment: You should solve your inital error when workign with the dict instead of working around it with this hack. Provide the initial version and error details.